# how to get the average star rating using entity framework .average() method

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, asp.net-mvc-4

I'm new in mvc and entity framework and I develop a star rating system for products. I'm trying to get the average star rating of a product and I built my database like this:

User table        : UserID PK , UserName , StarRatingDetails FK

Product Table     : ProdactID PK, ProudactName , StarRatingDetails FK

StarRatingDetails : ProdactID PK1 , UserID PK2 , VoteValue

so I'm trying to get the average star rate using the entity framework .average() method like this:

```
   var products = db.Products.Include(p => p.StarRatingDetail).ToList();
   var voteCounts = db.StarRatingDetail.ToList();

         foreach (var av in voteCounts)
        {
            var avarage = new { starAvarage = Convert.ToInt32(voteCounts.Average(avv => avv.VoteValue)) };

        }
```

It works and gets every average star rate of a product, but how can I associate the average rate with the correct product and send it to the view? If there's any other way I will be very thankful for any help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming `Product` has a `1..*` relationship with `StartRatingDetail`

```
var productWithVotes = db.Products.Include(p => p.StarRatingDetail)
                                  .Select(x => new {
                                      Product = x,
                                      VoteAverage = x.StarRatingDetail.Average(r => r.VoteValue)     
                                  });
```

Note - `Average` will throw an exception if the collection is empty therefore you might need a check before you call it

```
VoteAverage = x.StarRatingDetail.Any() ? 
    x.StarRatingDetail.Average(v => v.VoteValue) : 0
```

[Live example](http://ideone.com/ib16am)

Comment: it give me an error in this line 

VoteAverage = p.StarRatingDetail.Average(r => r.VoteValue)

the name p dose not exist in the current context

Comment: @Fadi typo, should be `x`.

Comment: ok i add a breakpoint to productWithVotes and in the Result view it give this error  base {"The cast to value type 'Double' failed because the materialized value is null. Either the result type's generic parameter or the query must use a nullable type."} System.SystemException {System.InvalidOperationException}

Comment: @Fadi I don't cast to `Double` anywhere in my example, clearly that's a separate issue with your code. See the example I have linked to.

Comment: ok thank u i try it without casting to int and it work fine so thank you alot for your help